# How to fix the error Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/prompt'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, reactive-programming

While I was compiling the code using `npm start` an error occurred.

When I try to solve this issue using `npm react-dev-utils` nothing happens and the issue remains the same.

Here is the error log:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find
>   module 'react-dev-utils/prompt' at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15) at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25) at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17) at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) at Object.
>   (C:\Users\cheru\smartshareapp\scripts\start.js:19:14) at
>   Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) at
>   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) npm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! Smartshare@0.1.0 start:
>   `node scripts/start.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the Smartshare@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\cheru\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-08T08_10_21_560Z-debug.log

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you check your package.json file to see what version it says for react-dev-utils? It should be the number after the @ symbol like react-dev-utils@0.2.0

Answer (score 1):

remove the folder `node_packages` and rerun `npm install again` it should be OK!
or rerun `npm install react-dev-utils --save`

Comment: iam already tried it but it is not working.any suggest any other solution